# Can I "convert" a US Enhanced Drivers License into a passport book?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, driving-licenses

I recently got an EDL (Enhanced Drivers License) in the US since I needed to get a new driver's license anyway. I would like to get a book for international travel eventually and I'm wondering if I have to apply like it's my first time getting one or if I can just apply for a renewal to get a book.

Comment: Enhanced Drivers License, functions as a passport card as well as a drivers license.

Comment: *I would like to get a book for international travel eventually and I'm wondering if I have to apply like it's my first time getting one or if I can just apply for a renewal to get a book* - can't you just put your current one into your "book"?

Comment: @Daniil I think OP is asking if they should use the renewal procedure to apply for a passport book (as is the case for holders of a proper passport card), or apply for a passport book as a first time applicant.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are in the US (since I only know that some Canadian provinces and US states issue EDLs, and Canada does not have a passport card), you would need to apply as a first time applicant.

An EDL is not actually a passport card, even though they both Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative compliant travel documents used for land and sea travel.

Passport (book and card) is issued by the federal government, whereas EDL is issued under state authority.

Comment: Do you have any evidence stating that an EDL does not qualify as a passport card?

Comment: @Daniil Well, the $35 first time execution fee is nominally for the US State department to process the request. A state-issued EDL doesn't mean State department has any less workload.

Comment: It was definitely more expensive to get the EDL, I think I had to make 2 separate payments for it. I did use it to get into Canada awhile back by road and it definitely has what appears to be a passport id on the back.

Comment: Mexico won't accept an EDL for entry into Mexico, but they will accept a Passport Card at land (and I think sea) borders

Comment: @zhantongz the execution fee goes to the application processor (for example the post office or the county clerk), not the Department of State.

Comment: @Pjstaab an EDL generally costs $30 more than a non-EDL license, at least that's how much more it costs in New York, and a passport card costs $30, and they have the same function (at least with respect to Canada), but none of that means that an EDL *is* a passport card.  It isn't.